# Xstream application bean not honored

Tags: xstream

Our batch app is based on a framework which initializes a "xtream" bean. I am trying to deifne the same bean at my application level for setting some allow types. But when I debug , I dont see my bean being used. Any thoughts?
My bean definition:

@Bean(name="xstream")
public XStream xstream() {

```
    XStream xstream =  new XStream(); 

    Class[] classes = new Class[1];
    classes[0]= NocationEntity.class;
    //This is what I need
    xstream.allowTypes(classes);

    //This is also  what I need
    xstream.allowTypesByWildcard(new String[]{
            "com.app.batch.custom.package.**" 

    });
```

I am expecting the above permissions to show when I debug the application locally and check for "xstream" bean